# Reading kerberos service ticket in Java

Tags: java, kerberos

I want to do simple thing like read the service ticket in java, want to get list of service tickets similar to output that we get by running klist. I have been searching for java example but most of it is about obtaining the service ticket.

Thanks

Comment: What is the purpose of your task? Oracle's impl could have a low-level API.

Comment: I'm trying to write a unit test to verify that we got the service ticket and it used Kerberos for authentication.

Comment: I am new to Kerberos, can you please explain what is meant by service ticket and how to create that in detail?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/7-b147/sun/security/krb5/internal/tools/Klist.java

Most of the standard kerberos utilities have java versions somewhere inside the jdk.